# Excluir trecho de string sempre que se repetir Python

Tags: python, string

Tenho um Dataframe que em uma determinada coluna existem muitos nomes e todos esses nomes possuem uma extensão do tipo:

- "NOME A_SOJA_2020.xlsx"
- "NOME B_SOJA_2020.XLSX"

Gostaria de desenvolver uma função ou um código para sempre remover o trecho "_SOJA_2020.xlsx" e só mantivesse o nome no DataFrame.
Estava fazendo no seguinte método:

```
df3['Nome da Seguradora'] = df3['Nome da Seguradora'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('Essor_Soja_2020.xls','Essor'))
```

Porém, fazer isso para cada nome no DataFrame não me parece a melhor solução, se alguém puder me ajudar a encontrar uma solução mais otimizada, agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente trocar o trecho indesejado por uma string vazia:

```
df3['Nome da Seguradora'] = df3['Nome da Seguradora'].apply(lambda x: str(x).replace('_Soja_2020.xls',''))
```

Comment: Nossa, que desatenção a minha... Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Não fiz o teste de performance, mas em geral usar funções pré-construídas é preferível ao uso do `apply`, só com o [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) fica assim:

```
df['Nome da Seguradora'].replace({'Soja_2020.xls' : ''}, regex=True, inplace = True)
```

Comment: Bom ponto, performou melhor mesmo. Obrigado